# Combine two mongoose aggregation pipeline into one where result of first pipeline is used in another pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named dummy .
It's schema is defined as -

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    Name: { type: String },
    start: { type: String },
    end: { type: String },
}
```

Now I want to fetch documents from the collection where `end < x` .
But here is a catch -

1. From the document matching above filter I do not want want those document for whose `Name` we can find another document where `start<=x<=end` .
2. And only one document for each `Name` should be fetched where end is closest to x.

I can achieve this in multiple aggregation pipeline by getting all the `Name` in `namesArr` where `start<=x<=end` in first aggregation pipeline and then using `{$nin:namesArr}` to remove documents with such names and then group by `Name` and insert all documents in decreasing sort and select first to get only one document for each bus where end is closest to x in second aggregation pipeline.
Example collection-

```
{Name : 'a', start :30, end :35},
{Name : 'a', start :40, end :50},
{Name : 'b', start :10, end :25},
{Name : 'b', start :30, end :35},
{Name : 'b', start :60, end :80},
```

So if x is 44 then the query should return only `{Name : 'b', start :30, end :35}`

But I want to achieve this in single aggregation pipeline because I do no want to fetch the namesArr first and then pass that in second aggregation pipeline.
So is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Normally, I would ask to see what you've already tried, but this question piqued my interest, so I made: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AxDouR8Pxx2

Comment: above aggregate pipeline worked for me and giving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the desired behaviour by calculating 4 helper fields.

1. `isInRange`: boolean, indicating whether `start<=x<=end`
2. `diffToX`: numeric, indicating the absolute difference of `x` and `end`
   By grouping of `Name` field, we get 2 more aggregated helper fields
3. `anyInRange`: boolean, by using `$max`, we check whether any `isInRange` is in the `Name` group. If any entry is in range, the final result will be true; otherwise will be false.
4. `rank`: int, computed rank by sorting `diffToX`. Entry with end closest to X should have the highest rank(i.e. smallest rank number)

By using the 4 helper fields, we can get your expected result in following steps:

1. compute `isInRange` and `diffToX` for every documents
2. compute `anyInRange` and `rank` in `$setWindowFields` with `"partitionBy": "$Name"` and `"sortBy": {"diffToX": 1}`
3. `$match` with end <= X and anyInRange: false
4. `$sort` with rank: 1 and `$limit: 1` to get the entry closest to X

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      isInRange: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                x: 44
              },
              in: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$start",
                      "$$x"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gte: [
                      "$end",
                      "$$x"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "then": true,
          "else": false
        }
      },
      diffToX: {
        "$abs": {
          "$subtract": [
            "$end",
            44
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$Name",
      "sortBy": {
        "diffToX": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "anyInRange": {
          "$max": "$isInRange"
        },
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      end: {
        $lt: 44
      },
      anyInRange: false
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      rank: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "anyInRange",
      "diffToX",
      "isInRange",
      "rank"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HO70o2qemYy)